# How to get query params of a request in interceptor Angular

Tags: angular, interceptor, query-string, angular-http-interceptors

I want to get the query params from an get request. Interceptor code is this way,

```js
export class FixtureInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

i tried to get the params using get method like this ,

```
req.params.get('category');
```

but it returns me null always. My api call is this way ,

```js
getValue() {
     return this.http.get('http://139.49.10.175:3000/laundryItems?category=2&type=4');
}
```

i need value of category and type from above API call

Comment: request.body.hasOwnProperty('category') can you check this giving result?

Comment: body is null , so it gives me this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null @GhazanfarKhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently params directly putted in url doesn't appear in `req.params`, this one should work:

```
  getValue() {
    return this.http.get('http://139.49.10.175:3000/laundryItems', {params: {category: '2', type: '4'}});
  }
```

Comment: What if this is an incoming request from an external source ?

Comment: @Dibzmania can't really get what you mean. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Is this auto encoded, or should this be handled here?

Comment: Doesn't work, even if you add the params via [routerLink]

Comment: @ΕГИІИО Can you please provide code?

Comment: @Buczkowski <a [routerLink]="['laundryItems']" [queryParams]="{ category: 2, type: 4 }"> I couldn't read these query params back in the interceptor as request.params. So I used headers instead.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО this is something else. Params are used to build url which is then used as endpoint http call. Query params are in your browser url and it can be accessed via app.

Answer (score 0):

Well... here we are again...  [HttpParams documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) states object is immutable.  Therefore, in order to build the collection we must do something like:

```
let params = new HttpParams().set("categoryName", "Cars");
if (search.length >= 2) {
  params = params.append("search", search);
}
```

Adding to `http.get` must take this form:

```
this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.baseUrl}products`, { params }).subscribe(result => {
  this.products = result;
}, error => {
  console.error(error)
});
```

> IMPORTANT:  The wrapping of `params` in brace-brackets is required - especially if you want to retrieve the params, like by some interceptor - for example:

```
let search = request.params.get("search");
```

Also, refer to [the section about using HttpParams](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings/#httpparams) in [this article](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings).